# Roundup average value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want my average which is found in the MongoDB aggregation to come up with a roundup value

```
 [
      {
        "_id": "581c3d9c55421c16ecaf0b26",
        "uDept": "CoE Design & Research",
        "uName": "Saurabh Raman",
        "rateVal": 3,
        "timeStamp": "11/4/2016 13:17",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "581c437ea3d9f6087ce3b21e",
        "uDept": "CoE Design & Research",
        "uName": "Sachin P Singh",
        "rateVal": 4,
        "timeStamp": "11/4/2016 13:42",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "581c6d74a3d9f6087ce3b21f",
        "uDept": "Training",
        "uName": "Rahul Shakya",
        "rateVal": 4,
        "timeStamp": "11/4/2016 16:35",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
```

The query which I run to obtain the average of "rateVal"

```
db.calcR.aggregate([
    {
            $group: {
                _id: null,  

                avg: {$avg: '$rateVal'},

            }
    }
```

The output is `{ avg: 3.6666 }` but ideally I want it to appear as 4

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "avg": 3.6666666666666665,

  }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

To round the value in mongoDb you can use either [$ceil](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/ceil/) or [$floor](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/)

```
db.calcR.aggregate([
    {
            $group: {
                _id: null,  

                avg: {$avg: '$rateVal'},

            },
           $project:{
               _id: '$_id' ,
               roundedAvg : { $ceil: '$avg' }
           }
    }]
```

Output look like

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "roundedAvg": 4,

  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since by documentation unary operator accumulators(eg: $round) are not allowed at $group stage, you can use them at $addFields stage. This way, in your case, the avg field defined at group stage will be overwritten by $addFields stage:

```
   $addFields: {
    avg: { $round: ['$avg', -1] },
  },
```

Comment: Can you give the whole code? I am still getting the error A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field .

Comment: Here it is @SlowSnail:
`
db.calcR.aggregate([
    {
            $group: {
                _id: null,  

                avg: {$avg: '$rateVal'},

            }
    },
  {
   $addFields: {
    avg: { $round: ['$avg', -1] },
  },
}]
`

Comment: $round is available only after 4.2. I am using 3.6 now so anyway to round up the $avg for 3.6?